# How can I transfer a zip file directly from a URL to HDFS by using Java?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I transfer a zip file  from a URL to HDFS by using Java? I am not supposed to download it. I can only transfer the file directly from URL to HDFS. Anyone has some idea would work out?

Comment: You cannot accomplish this in the manner that you have described the requirements. HDFS is a file system. HDFS has no intelligence or the ability to run Java programs. The Java program would run outside of HDFS using HDFS as its destination. This means that you have to download the data in some manner before storing it to HDFS. Even if this means using streams block by block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple ssh code like:

```
wget http://domain/file.zip
```

and then

```
hadoop fs -put /path/file.zip
```

In java, you should download the file and then put it in hdfs

Comment: I am not supposed to download it. I can only transfer the file directly from URL to HDFS. Do you have any idea would work out?

Comment: You must download the file before putting it in HDFS

Comment: That's not true. You can use Java API to stream bytes to an in-memory file, then upload it